# How to replace same occurrences with different strings in linux

Tags: linux, awk, sed

I have already seen few similar type questions, but I have a different situation here to post it. 
I have to replace different strings to same occurences in a file. I have used

`sed -i 's/X/Y/g' file.txt`

For similar occurence I have used line numbers like

`sed -i '3s/X/Y/g ; 4s/X/Z/g' file.txt`

This is possible only if those strings are always in same line.

Ex : file.txt

This color is

...*some more lines*

This color is

...*some more lines*

This color is

...*some more lines*

This color is

...*some more lines*`

I need to change them as

This color is blue

...*some more lines*

This color is red

...*some more lines*

This color is green

...*some more lines*

This color is yellow

...*some more lines*

Without using line numbers. As the line numbers for those strings can change anytime if more info is added?

Can anyone please help. Thank you

Comment: `perl -pe 'BEGIN{@a=("blue","red","green","yello")} s/$/$a[$v++%4]/ if /This color is/' input-file`

Comment: @WilliamPursell I can't use perl. I need to do it on command prompt

Comment: You can invoke `perl` from the shell just like you invoke `awk`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`awk` to the rescue!

this will cycle through the colors if there are more lines than the colors

```
$ awk -v colors='blue,red,green,yellow' 'BEGIN {n=split(colors,v,",")}
                                       /color/ {$0=$0 OFS v[i++%n+1]}1' file
```

to embed this into a quoted string, it will be easier to remove double quotes altogether.  Simply change to

```
$ awk -v colors='blue red green yellow' 'BEGIN {n=split(colors,v)}
                                       /color/ {$0=$0 OFS v[i++%n+1]}1' file
```

if your colors are not single words, you can't use the above, so back to splitting with comma (or any other delimiter), just need to escape them

```
$ awk -v colors='true blue,scarlet red,pistachio green,canary yellow' '
                       BEGIN {n=split(colors,v,\",\")}
                     /color/ {$0=$0 OFS v[i++%n+1]}1' file
```

Comment: One quick question. In my code I need to put it inside " ". Its giving me an error as quotes in (colors,v,",") is seperating the line.

Comment: I didn't understand, what do you need to double quote. The script or the color values?

Comment: I need to put this whole thing in " " as I am passing it to command prompt thru perl program. something like ->cmd(" "); between " " goes this code. But it is breaking I have used \" but still error. cmd is a function I wrote which opens cmd and writes the command there.

Comment: like sed doesn't awk save the file?

Comment: I'm still not sure how you're going to use it, but see the update that removes the double quotes from the script.

Comment: I need to add (blue one,red two,green three)[more than one word for each line. When I use the updated one, I get the result as This is blue,This is one,This is red,This is two.

Comment: In my program I place all the commands I have to  run in the command prompt in " ". When I put awk -v colors='blue,red,green,yellow' 'BEGIN {n=split(colors,v,",")}
                                       /color/ {$0=$0 OFS v[i++%n+1]}1' file           The cmd takes only takes till v,"

Comment: if you use double quotes inside double quotes, you need to escape them. Please see the update

Answer (score 2):

Your question isn't clear but it SOUNDS like you're trying to do this:

```
awk 'NR==FNR{colors[NR];next} /This color is/{$0 = $0 OFS colors[++c]} 1' colors file
```

where `colors` is a file containing one color per line and `file` is the file you want the color values added to. If that's not what you want then edit your question to specify your requirements more clearly and come up with a better (and complete/testable) example.